# Hierarchical clustering with custom distance

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka

I need to implement a hierarchical clustering algorithm based on a custom distance. The distance is computed by looking in a database for the value associated to the two ids of the objects that are being compared.
Is there an easy way to do this in Java? I took a look at Weka and their custom distance function but I cannot find a way to define instances so that when I am in the custom distance function I can get the IDs of the two original objects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks a lot in advance
Rossella

Comment: http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions

They have SLINK, which is single-link hierarchical clustering in O(n^2) runtime (instead of O(n^3), which is the trivial way of implementing it). You'll probably need to do load a fake data set containing your IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on Apache Mahout.
Here is a link [Mahout Hierarchical clustering](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/top-down-clustering.html)

This tool is written in Java and its open source.

Comment: ... and it doesn't play well with other databases, by design.